# Meaning of 間合いを外す

Tags: meaning

In the context of two opponents facing off each other. Does it mean reducing or increasing the distance between the two? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would mean "to increase the distance" to use your own words.

「[間合]{まあ}いを[外]{はず}す」 means "to sidestep", "to dodge", etc. in the one-on-one type of sports and martial arts.

Your exact context is unknown, but the phrase could not possibly mean the opposite.

Comment: As an aside, the opposite is 間合いを詰【つ】める.